# Plugin for JIRA throws errors in 7.4.1 but runs well in 7.4.2

Tags: maven, dependencies, jira, jira-plugin

I want to port my plugin for JIRA to make it compatible with JIRA 7.4.x
When I change the version of JIRA to 7.4.1 in pom.xml I get the following compilation errors:

```
package com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api does not exist
package org.apache.velocity does not exist
package org.apache.velocity.app does not exist
package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist
class file for com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.Group not found 
class file for com.atlassian.plugin.web.Condition not found
```

When I set the version to 7.4.2, I can compile the plugin, and also run it in JIRA without problems.
[Here](https://pastebin.com/hYNxFkqr) is a paste with properties and dependencies of my pom.xml.
What can we do to make the plugin also compatible with JIRA 7.4.1 ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `<import-package>` instructions in the maven-jira-plugin in my pom.xml to solve this. 
Docu: https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins

Also [this answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Why-am-I-getting-quot-Unresolved-constraint-in-bundle-quot/qaq-p/557505) solved my further classpath / dependency errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have started with atlassian plugins and development a while ago, and I think that some parts of those packages are added in 7.4.2, so they are not usable in 7.4.1 (this is my opinion). I can only give you my opinion since I've had the problems with atlassian sdk myself and had to solve them alone since the documentation on official atlassian is not so great.

I found [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/JIRA-6-api-changes-after-jira-upgrade-Plugin-not-working/qaq-p/491118) article and [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-create-plugin-in-a-different-jira-version/qaq-p/498736) one with the similar problem to yours, you can check it out since it's marked as "solved", hope it will help you.